# Unable To Rename Directory With Open File Handle

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

On Windows 10 within my Ubuntu Subsystem, when I open a file in a directory and try to rename that directory while that file is open, I am unable to do so.

Example:

```
$mkdir demo
$touch demo/test.txt
$CtlZ
$[2]+  Stopped                 vim demo/test.txt
$mv demo demo100
mv: cannot move 'demo' to 'demo100': Permission denied
```

And now when I close the file I can rename it.

```
$mv demo demo100
$ls demo100
test.txt
```

This seems like unexpected behavior.  When I do the same test on a regular Ubuntu box, I am able to rename the file without a problem.  Any ideas as to what might cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is normal Windows behaviour.  Under windows, opening a file effectively locks it on the file system and prevents it from being moved.

It's important to understand that WSL is NOT a virtual machine.  It is a (thin) layer on top of windows which gives Posix like access onto windows.  So when you open a file under WSL, you are in fact opening it under windows and are subject to the usual rules of windows.

**Reading:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux

> **Overview**
>
> WSL provides a Linux-compatible kernel interface developed by
>   Microsoft (containing no Linux kernel code), which can then run a
>   GNU user space on top of it, such as that of Ubuntu,
>   openSUSE, SUSE Linux Enterprise Server, Debian and
>   Kali Linux.

Further

> **Hardware and filesystem access**
>
> As there is no hardware emulation / virtualization (unlike other projects such as coLinux), WSL makes direct use of the host file system